# installation of MariaDB is failing due to a missing library: libssl.1.0.0.dylib on mac

Tags: macos, openssl, mariadb, homebrew

my mac version is 13.5.1(intel).
got below error while installation of mariaDB through one of the application.
An error occurred while installing the database
at ch.vorburger.mariadb4j.DB.install(DB.java:129)
at ch.vorburger.mariadb4j.DB.newEmbeddedDB(DB.java:76)
at com.santaba.latenvironment.db.BuiltInMysql.newDB(BuiltInMysql.java:57)
at com.santaba.latenvironment.db.LATMysqlDb.newDB(LATMysqlDb.java:53)
at com.santaba.latenvironment.db.LATDBServer.main(LATDBServer.java:82)
Caused by: ch.vorburger.exec.ManagedProcessException: Program [/var/folders/c3/yv5dj8tn19g0qyls_5hhhnm80000gn/T/MariaDB4j/base/bin/mysql_install_db, --datadir=/private/var/folders/c3/yv5dj8tn19g0qyls_5hhhnm80000gn/T/MariaDB4j/data/10000, --basedir=/private/var/folders/c3/yv5dj8tn19g0qyls_5hhhnm80000gn/T/MariaDB4j/base, --no-defaults, --force, --skip-name-resolve] (in working directory /var/folders/c3/yv5dj8tn19g0qyls_5hhhnm80000gn/T/MariaDB4j/base) failed, exitValue=1, last 100 lines of console:
dyld[19114]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
Referenced from:  /private/var/folders/c3/yv5dj8tn19g0qyls_5hhhnm80000gn/T/MariaDB4j/base/bin/my_print_defaults
Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib' (no such file)

also tried to install openssl 1.0 but it failed and got following error
brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0` not working anymore https://github.com/rbenv/homebrew-tap/issues/1
Error when installing openssl version 1.0 (MacOS Big Sur, Version 11.7.6. i7) https://github.com/rbenv/homebrew-tap/issues/9

Comment: Make sure you have OpenSSL installed : `brew list | grep openssl`.

Why don't you use Docker ?

Comment: @drino My OpenSSL version is 3.1.2, installed on August 1, 2023, and it's being used by my Java application and a MariaDB wrapper that internally relies on OpenSSL 1.0. I attempted to install OpenSSL 1.0 using 'brew install rbenv/tap/openssl@1.0,' but the installation failed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so in this context, you could maybe try to "trick" MaridaDB by doing a symlink to your actual version.. But I don't think this is a good idea..

I think you really should go for a Docker container that fit perfectly to that kind of use case.